# Call a Java Agent from a Java Class in XPages

Tags: xpages

I'm able to call a Java agent in SSJS with the following code:

```
var db:NotesDatabase = session.getCurrentDatabase();
var agent:NotesAgent = db.getAgent("AgentName");
agent.run();
```

But what I'm wanting to do is to call a Java agent from a Java class? Is this possible? Thanks for any tips.

Comment: It's certainly possible. You "just" convert your SSJS code to the equivalent java code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interesting challenge is to get hands on the session and/or database inside your Java class. The class could be in your NSF, in a plug-in, or a jar in jvm/lib/ext.

You don't want to depend on where it came from, so you use dependency injection to provide them (which is a fancy word for: provide as parameter) something like:

```
public class Leon implements Serializable {

      public void cleanerDoYourWork(Database db) {
            Agent theProfessional = db.getAgent("acidAndGuns");
            theProfessional.run();
            theProfessional.recycle();
      }
    }
```

In case you don't get the pun, search IMDB for Leon :-)

Remark: In SSJS you don't need `session.getCurrentDatabase();`, it is already there as "database"

Comment: I think there's a bug. Shouldn't it be <code>Leon implements SerialKiller</code> :-)